# Oracle Cannot retain data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have oracle database installed on my system

I access it through command line.

```
win+r > cmd > sqlplus
```

I had created a user

```
system
```

and

```
password system
```

I created a table

```
create table users ( username varchar(20));
```

Inserted few records.

```
insert into users (username ) values ('user1');
insert into users (username ) values ('user2');
```

then I exit

```
>exit
```

Problem is that when I try to login again.

table is still there. But the data which I had inserted is gone.

```
select * from users;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
no rows selected
```

Comment: I don't think you actually created a user 'SYSTEM' - that's a default, administrative account. you should not be using it for storing data, ever.

Comment: type commit and hit enter after you insert data. Otherwise data will be lost once you log out of the session. Oracle (R.D.B.M.S)is different from mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SQL*Plus** has option to auto-commit:

```
SET AUTO[COMMIT]{ON | OFF | IMM[EDIATE] | n}
```

From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm):

- ON commits pending changes to the database after Oracle Database executes each successful INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE, or PL/SQL block.
- OFF suppresses automatic committing so that you must commit changes manually.
- `SET AUTOCOMMIT` does not alter the commit behavior when SQL*Plus exits. **Any uncommitted data is committed by default.**

To control the commit on `EXIT`, you need to set the **EXITCOMMIT** parameter in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> show exitcommit
exitcommit ON
SQL> set exitcommit off
```

If it's et to OFF, then you need to explicitly **COMMIT** after the insert statement which is a DML transaction. Create table is a DDL statement which does an implicit commit.

```
insert into users (username ) values ('user1');
insert into users (username ) values ('user2');
COMMIT; --> add this
```

> I have created a user system

`SYSTEM` is an administrative user account which is automatically created when you install Oracle database. It is meant for administration tasks and not to store application data etc. Create a separate user for your application.

Comment: mysql and oracle are two different worlds. I have been using mysql. It does require you to commit data.But apparently Oracle does require commit.

Comment: In this case, it is the **SQL*Plus** client tool's parameter which controls the AUTOCOMMIT on EXIT. But in general, any DML transaction should be explicitly committed.